# pd.MultiIndex: How do I add 1 more level (0) to a multi-index column?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

This sounds trivial, but I just can't add 1 more level of index to the columns of a multi-level column df.

**Current State**

```
Category | Cat1       | Cat2 |
         |Total Assets| AUMs |
Firm 1   | 100        | 300  |
Firm 2   | 200        | 3400 |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  |
```

**Desired State**

```
Importance | H        | H    |
Category | Cat1       | Cat2 |
         |Total Assets| AUMs |
Firm 1   | 100        | 300  |
Firm 2   | 200        | 3400 |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  |
```

When I use the below code

**Code 1: Error: isnull is not defined for MultiIndex**

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['H','H'],df.columns])
```

**Code 2: Error 1st level Name become a combination**

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['H','H'],df.columns.value])

Importance | H                          | H            |
Category   | (Cat1, Total Assets)       | (Cat2, AUMs) |

Firm 1   | 100        | 300  |
Firm 2   | 200        | 3400 |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()`:

```
df=pd.concat([df],keys=['H'],names=['Importance'],axis=1)
```

Comment: @Anurag Dabas: `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['H','H'],df.columns]) ` works if df only has a single level of columns, but why it doesn't work when df has multi-level columns? Thanks

Comment: @Peter because of MultiIndex so for that case use `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['H','H'],df.columns.levels[0],df.columns.levels[1]],names=['Importance','Category',None])`